# python デコレーターでのエラー

Tags: python

処理の最初と最後にログを出すためにデコレーターを採用しようとしているのですが、戻り値がdictだとエラーになってしまいます。
まだデコレーターに関して詳しくなくエラーの原因がないか分からず困っております。

```
def args_logger(fnc):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        print('--start {}--'.format(fnc.__name__))
        print('args: {} kwargs: {}'.format(args,kwargs))
        fnc(*args,**kwargs)
        print('--end {}--'.format(fnc.__name__))
        
    return wrapper

@args_logger
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    d = fnc_a()
    print(str(d))
    print(d['key'])

@args_logger
def fnc_a():
    print('fnc_a処理')
    dic = {'key':'value'}
    return dic
```

dicを返しているのですが受け取れずnoneになってしまいます。
デコレーターを外すとうまく処理されます。
どうしたら正常に戻り値を受け取れるようになるのか？教えてください。

Comment: デコレータで `fnc(*args,**kwargs)` としているので戻り値がありません。例えば、`ret = fnc(*args,**kwargs)` として、`print('--end {}--'.format(fnc.__name__))` の次に `return ret` とでもするとよいかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
これで解決できました。